# Server does not respond to manual request

Tags: http, ssl, openssl, http-headers, httprequest

I'm trying to connect to *api.poloniex.com* on port 443 (SSL). They are using a WebSocket/Wamp server on that port which is pushing data. I've already tried to connect with *Autobahn|JS* and it works.

Before the data transmission begins, a **Http-Upgrade-Request** is sent to the server, which indicates that the client wants to switch from *http to websocket*. Then the server normally responds with  *101 - Switching protocols*.

Using the *Autobahn|JS* library, the request looks like this:

**Request:**

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: api.poloniex.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Origin: ...
Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: wamp.2.json
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate
Sec-WebSocket-Key: 0n4ibEwIyTMDMhKoxXt+Cg==
Cookie: ......
Connection: keep-alive, Upgrade
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Upgrade: websocket
```

**Response:**

```
HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Server: Crossbar/0.10.4
X-Powered-By: AutobahnPython/0.10.4
Upgrade: WebSocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: wamp.2.json
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: dbaqDVdVW+xtbCa2V0yjtb7yXqI=
```

I tried to manually send the Request-Header. I used `openssl s_client -connect api.poloniex.com:443` to connect with SSL-encryption. Then I sent a slightly modified header (I removed Origin and Cookie):

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: api.poloniex.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: wamp.2.json
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate
Sec-WebSocket-Key: czW+w3Z+3yZCKVGx6DQ1Rg==
Connection: keep-alive, Upgrade
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Upgrade: websocket
```

But then, the server does not answer. It does not even close the connection, just nothin happens at all. I've also tried to leave the Cookie and Origin fields in, but that does also not work.

**Edit:** Sending the message this way does also not work:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: api.poloniex.com\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0\r\nAccept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\nAccept-Language: de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nSec-WebSocket-Version: 13\r\nSec-WebSocket-Protocol: wamp.2.json\r\nSec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate\r\nSec-WebSocket-Key: czW+w3Z+3yZCKVGx6DQ1Rg==\r\nConnection: keep-alive, Upgrade\r\nPragma: no-cache\r\nCache-Control: no-cache\r\nUpgrade: websocket\r\n\r\n
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Web Apps Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP requests have a line end of `\r\n` but often single `\n` will be accepted. But what you probably missed is the final empty line which is the end of header marker. Thus the server still waits for the end of the header.

Comment: I have pressed enter twice at the end. I also tested the REST-API of Poloniex this way and it worked.

Comment: @Bobface: works for me if I use the `-crlf` option with s_client to make sure that the line endings are correct.

Comment: It works now with the -crlf! But could you tell me where the difference is between this command and typing the \r\n's manually?

Comment: @Bobface: I have no idea how you "typed" `\r\n`, but typing backslash-r will definitely not result in a CR (`\r`).